# Sqlbulkcopyoptions.firetriggers does not fire trigger in the table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, triggers

I have a table with a trigger newly added to it.

When I try to run a batch file and upload the file using SqlBulkCopy it did not work.

After reading that adding SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers will fire the triggers that are set to the table, I added it.

But still I get the same error - 'Bulk copy failed. User does not have ALTER TABLE permission on table. ALTER TABLE permission is required on the target table of a bulk copy operation if the table has triggers or check constraints, but 'FIRE_TRIGGERS' or 'CHECK_CONSTRAINTS' bulk hints are not specified as options to the bulk copy command.
'

Any idea what is to be done? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to assign `ALTER TABLE` permissions?

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without the alter table permissions?

Comment: You need to also add SqlBulkCopyOption.CheckConstraints if the invoking user doesn't have `ALTER TABLE` permission.

Comment: `code`using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))          `code` OR                                          `code` using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers , SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints)).         `code`                                                  Can you please confirm if its the first one? The second one had build errors

Comment: It's the first one. I don't see a constructor overload for the second form in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. Could you also help me understand why my constraints needs to checked when triggers are one that is not fired. The table also has 3 constraints to it.. I am novice in this and your advice is valued.

Comment: I'll add an answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server requires `ALTER TABLE` permissions to bulk insert data without the FireTriggers and CheckConstraint options, as well as with the KeepIdentity option, to help safeguard against minimally-privileged users from violating data integrity rules enforced by SQL Server.  See [What permission do I need to use SqlBulkCopy in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655293/what-permission-do-i-need-to-use-sqlbulkcopy-in-sql-server-2008).

The FireTriggers and CheckConstraint options of SqlBulkCopy are off by default to maximize performance.  It is the application's responsibility  to ensure data integrity that would otherwise be enforced by constraints and triggers when these options are off. Foreign key and check constraints become not trusted after data are bulk copied without these options and must be re-validated with ALTER TABLE...CHECK CONSTRAINT` afterwards before SQL Server will trust the constraints again.

No special permissions other than `SELECT/INSERT` to use SqlBulkCopy when FireTriggers and CheckConstraint options are on, and the KeepIdentity option is off.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding Checkconstraints as well but it says the same error.

using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))

Is there another way to do it?