# SQL Server Service Broker is not working Properly

Tags: sql-server

I implemented the Service Broker Functionality in database and Configuration works fine. But when I insert 4 rows into a base table then my trigger is called only once instead of four time. This is misbehaving to me and some times at does not insert any data in table.

Trigger code as

```
CREATE   TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Insert_BaseTable]
 ON [dbo].[BaseTable]
 FOR INSERT
 AS BEGIN
        DECLARE @InitDlgHandle AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
       BEGIN DIALOG @InitDlgHandle
            FROM SERVICE [InitiatorService]
            TO SERVICE N'TargetService'
            ON CONTRACT [SampleContract]
            WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

        -- Send a message on the conversation           
        SEND ON CONVERSATION (@InitDlgHandle) MESSAGE TYPE [RequestMessage];
       COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
```

Activation SP Code is as

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     WAITFOR (RECEIVE TOP (1) @RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle, @RecvReqMsg = message_body, @RecvReqMsgName = message_type_name FROM TargetQueue),  TIMEOUT 5000;
     IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
         BEGIN
             ROLLBACK;
             BREAK;
         END
     IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'RequestMessage'
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
       ([MySSN]
       ,[MyName]
       ,[MyEmail]
       ,[MyInt])
 VALUES
       (1234567890
       ,'Steve Jones'
       ,'SomeSteve@SomeDomain.com'
       ,10
       )
        END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
     END
     ELSE
         IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'
             BEGIN
                 END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
             END
         ELSE
             IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
                 BEGIN
                     END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
                 END
     COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 END
```

This sp is bound to Service and Trigger send message to the Queue. For every row insert in a base table it should insert a new row in a new table by using this SP. I am using idea in a link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/10/19/using-sql-service-broker-for-asynchronous-external-script-r-python-execution-in-oltp-systems/ I just want to execute one SP instead of two and in a trigger I Don't want to pass message parameter like SEND ON CONVERSATION (@InitDlgHandle) MESSAGE TYPE [RequestMessage]; 
Any immediate help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is intended behavior of table triggers, which execute once per batch (not once per row). Note this also means it runs for empty record sets.
If you need to do something on every row, then write a cursor in the trigger.

Comment: An alternative to having a cursor in the trigger as @Elaskanator suggests, you can generate and send a message that represents (in your example) all four rows via SB and then process it as such.

Comment: Thanks Elaskanator and Ben. After getting idea from your comments, I run Scripts with GO after each insert and It works fine for me in SSMS. But our data comes from another app on which we don't have control, in this case our Queue is not Activated and SP is not Called. We cannot change the way how data is inserted from App. Can you please tell me some other ways how Can we invoke the Queue like SP or other.

Comment: A trigger definition is very similar to a stored procedure. Since you can't change the data insert process (nor the service broker queue?) just modify the trigger to iterate over each row in the `inserted` table to call the queue.
However, you appear to be asking an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)  because your service broker queue call isn't even using anything from the inserted rows (or you omitted critical parts of your functional code), so it looks like you're just writing an overcomplicated hit counter.

Comment: I change the trigger to a simple insert into a another table. it works fine when i insert data into base table from SSMS but When Data come from APP sevre then Trigger does not fire. No issue looks with the implementation of the Service Broker. Any reason that my trigger is not being fired from outside of SQL Server?

Comment: In C#, the BulkCopy functionality by default disables trigger firing. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44810778/2799848). tl;dr Bypassing triggers is done for performance reasons when bulk inserting records, but requires ALTER permissions because it is disabling the table trigger behind the scenes before it does the import (and then re-enables after it's done). You'll have to check with the application team on what they're doing, since it should be impossible to avoid firing triggers (without disabling them).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop while sending messages to the queue with the count of the inserted rows at trigger.

```
declare @cnt int =0, @i int=1;
select @cnt=count(1) from inserted;
while (@i<=@cnt)
begin
select * from(
select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rrn from inserted) where rrn=@i;
/*
Send your RequestMessage to the broker
*/
end
```